# Structural Typing for Traversable

Tags: scala, structural-typing

I have this method:

```
scala> def foo(traversable: Traversable[{def toByte: Byte}]) = {
     | traversable.map(_.toByte)
     | }
foo: (traversable: Traversable[AnyRef{def toByte: Byte}])Traversable[Byte]
```

But when I call it like so:

`scala> foo(List(1,2,3))`

I get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.toByte(Unknown Source)
    at $anonfun$foo$1.apply(<console>:8)
    at $anonfun$foo$1.apply(<console>:8)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:45)
    at .foo(<console>:8)
```

But when I do something like this:

```
scala> 1.toByte
res1: Byte = 1
```

It works.

I'm probably missing something so basic that I'm overlooking it, but how can I make this work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Int` [is sybtype of](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/128) `AnyVal`, so you need explicitly declare it.

```
def foo(xs: Traversable[AnyVal { def toByte: Byte }]) = xs.map(_.toByte)
```